# Movie Player Did Finish Notification is not fire in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I played the movie but **can't able to called the method when the movie is finished.**

**My code is as follow:**

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *pv=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[arr_videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Video_path"]]];

MPMoviePlayerController *pc=[pv moviePlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:pv];

[self presentViewController:pv animated:YES completion:nil];

[pc prepareToPlay];

[pc play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This code for Media Player.

```
MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:URL or Path of file];
    theMovie.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(60, 20, 700, 500);
    theMovie.view.center = self.view.center;

    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];

    // Register for the playback finished notification. 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(onStop) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:theMovie];



-(void)onStop
{
    NSLog(@"Movie Stopped");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...!! But it only shows the black screen & video is not played

Comment: [theMovie play] needs to be used to play it.

Comment: yes, already tried this but got the same result. If i use `MoviePlayerViewController` then it plays fine but the delegate method is not called.

Comment: i have already implemented in one my application and its working fine.

Comment: then what should i do??

Comment: have you checked the path of audio file is correct?? when player doesn't get file then also it can happen..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33877/discussion-between-armaan-stranger-and-user2526811)

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: please take the `MPMoviePlayerController` object as global rather than  local instance.

Comment: really?? i don't think that it is going to make any difference to the work of movie player. but if it has worked like that then cheers for that.

Comment: okkk if it helped you then you can tick answer as accepted and upvote the answer.